# C# Monitor.Enter SynchronizationLockException

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, synchronization, thread-safety

i'm developing a C# 4.5 application in which many threads will need to access the same serial port.

Since i'll be receiving responses on the serial port too, i want to avoid further writing until i receive a response and read it.

I have a SerialHandler class which is a wrapper for the SerialPort class, the write and read methods look something like this:

```
public void write(string message)
{
  Monitor.Enter(lockingObject);
  //Stuff
  serialPort.write(message);
}

public string read()
{
  //Reading procedure
  Monitor.Exit(lockingObject);
}
```

But as soon as i issue a write from a form i get the SynchronizationLockException saying "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code".
lockingObject is a private and readonly Object variable.

How can i avoid this error?
Thanks a lot

Edit, it should work like this:
Thread A gains access to read/write
Thread B tries to gain access but fails
Thread A gets to read so he releases his lock
Thread B can now execute write, get his lock, read and remove his lock

Comment: Why use monitor directly instead of lock?

Comment: Because i need to lock the access in a method and release it in another one

Comment: The exception says that you called read() *before* calling write().  That's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown because different thread is [trying to release the object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationlockexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This is a simple solution to your problem:

```
class MySerialPort
{
    private AutoResetEvent _waithandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    private SerialPort _serialPort;

    public void write(string message)
    {
        _waithandle.WaitOne();
        //Stuff
        _serialPort.Write(message);
    }

    public string read()
    {
        try
        {
           ...
           ...
        }
        finally
        {
            _waithandle.Set();
        }
    }

}
```

first thread will write, then any new write operation will be blocked until the read will release one of them.

**Edit**

I saw in the comments below that your are looking for the fastest solution.
acording to to this [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_ManualResetEvent), the below code will do the job in 60ns(on Intel Core i7 860) which is much better

```
class MySerialPort
{
    private ManualResetEventSlim _waithandle = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    private readonly object _sync = new object();

    public void write(string message)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _waithandle.Wait();
            //Stuff
            _serialPort.Write(message);
            _waithandle.Reset();
        }

    }

    public string read()
    {
        try
        {
         ....
        }
        finally
        {
            _waithandle.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got a question tho, if waitCounter is 0, WaitOne will be called. Is this meant to happen? Won't it wait for nothing since no one will call Set?

Comment: `Interlocked.Increment` return the value after increase, so you won't block the first thread....

Comment: Oh i see, many thanks! So it'll always wait unless the value is 0

Comment: @MarcoBellan Yes it's wait until the value is 0. Now I am using a computer with VS. I forgot that you initialize WaitHandles with init state. So you don't need the counter.... I saw that you are looking for the fastest solution so I update my answer with a user mode synchronization. By the way please mark the answer as accept, so the question will no longer active.

Comment: Sorry i've been out last day, i can't understand the new code  
Why is the lock necessary in the write procedure? What does the Reset do in this case, and why is there no locking on read?

Comment: In above code example, I use `ManualResetEventSlim` which is the user mode implementation of `ManualResetEvent`. When the event is in a nonsignal mode the `Wait` method will block any thread. The `Reset` method changes the state of the event into nonsignal mode. The `Set` method changes the event state into signal mode. The `lock` verifies the only one thread write at a time and the event verifies that the next thread will wait until the read operation done. You don't need any `lock` operation on the read.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you so much for your help! i'll try it out tomorrow since i don't have access to the source control server on weekend

Comment: @MarcoBellan I'm curious... Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes i did, works perfectly and implemented it in other situations too, Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

You could use Mutex

```
class SerialHandler 
{
    private Mutex _mutex = new Mutex();
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    public void write(string message)
    {
      _mutex.WaitOne();
      //Stuff
      _serialPort.write(message);
    }

    public string read()
    {
      //Reading procedure
      _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

The problem means that you've tried releasing the unacquired lock.

Comment: oh i tought they would, don't they work exactly like the "lock" keyword? I never had these problems with lock. It's the first time i use Monitor tho and i'm relatively new to multithreading, thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: `lock` must be used used by one, synchronized block of code, so it is by definition used by the same thread. Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit are invoked in that case, but they're always called within the same thread.

Comment: Well i need it to be called by the same thread: something like:
Thread A gains access to read/write
Thread B tries to gain access but fails
Thread A gets to read so he releases his lock
Thread B can now execute write, get his lock, read and remove his lock

Comment: I thought that the flow of operations is a) mark line as "busy" b) write to the port c) read the result d) mark line as free. As suggested in the first post.

Comment: @RyszardFiński Yes it is. It needs to be really fast code since there'll be loads of call, Mutex seems to be slower tho, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: There is no simple answer - WaitHandles, Mutexes and Spinlocks have their use cases, but mutexes are slower. Keep in mind, that serial port's bandwidth is fairly limited, so I see this as your first bottleneck in terms of performance. You might as well use WaitHandle, but I see serial port as a mutex candidate. Monitor is really a resource aquisition for thread while mutex/waithandle are universal resource aquisition mechanisms for the process.